# Using moment.js how do I set day(0) as Sunday this week instead of previous week

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, momentjs, iso

I'm using moment.js and I'm doing the following:

```js
moment().startOf('isoWeek').day(0)
```

Instead of giving me the Sunday for this week - 25th, it returns the previous Sunday, 18th.

I have days from 0-6 saved in the database (1 = Monday, 0 = Sunday)

How can I use 0 to get *this* week's Sunday and not the previous Sunday?

**Edit:** Thanks for all the replies. I think I'll just add a week to the date for now but longer term will probably switch over to use `date-fns` across the project. Thanks.

Comment: Why not `moment().endOf('isoWeek')`?

Comment: @RobG: `endOf('isoWeek')` should indeed get you the correct Sunday, but returns `23:59:59.999` for time (which you may or may not want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `startOf('isoWeek')` uses Monday as the first day of the week, `.day(0)` uses the ECMAScript definition and takes you back another day (because based on its definition the Sunday *before* the Monday belongs to the respective week).

To work around it and get the upcoming Sunday, add another week using moment's `add` function as described on https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/01-add/:

```js
moment().startOf('isoWeek').day(0).add(1, 'weeks')
```

or use the shorthand as suggested on https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/02-get-set/06-day/:

```
moment().startOf('isoWeek').day(7);
```

Comment: Good point @RobG, my original answer wording actually was a bit off. I edited it, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

In moment.js the week **starts** on Sunday and ends on Saturday. This is a common format for calendars (although not one I prefer).

You can make it wrap around by setting the day to `8` instead of `0`.

---

That said, the developers of Moment.js themselves say "[We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode.](https://momentjs.com/docs/)" and list a number of reasons why you might not want to use it.

A popular alternative is date-fns which would allow you to write code like this:

```html
<script type=module>
import { nextSunday, formatISO, startOfWeek } from 'https://esm.run/date-fns';

const today = new Date();
const start = startOfWeek(today, { weekStartsOn: 1 }); // 1 is Monday
const sunday = nextSunday(today)
console.log(formatISO(sunday));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add + 7 after 0 to have the "next" sunday. Like this :

> const date = moment().startOf("isoWeek").day(0 + 7);
> console.log("date", date);

In english, a week start with a Sunday. That's why your code send back to you the "previous" sunday. Because this week is already started.

But be careful, Moment.Js si now depreciated. I recommend you to use date.fns for your project.